# Multiprocessing when saving excel files in a loop in python

Tags: python, for-loop, multiprocessing

I want to apply multiprocessing for the script below that saves the excel files in a for loop.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'month': [1, 4, 7, 10]})

for i in df.index:
    df.to_excel(str(df['month'][i])+'.xlsx')
    print(i)
```

I tried but can't get the results:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def savexls(df):
    for i in df.index:
        df.to_excel(str(df['month'][i])+'.xlsx')
        print(i)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool()              
    pool.map(savexls, df)
```

Can you help me with that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`map` will do the for loop

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def savexls(x):
    pd.to_excel(x)
    print(x)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    lst = [str(df['month'][i])+'.xlsx' for i in df.index]
    pool = Pool()              
    pool.map(savexls, lst)
```

Comment: I think pd.to_excel(x) should be df.to_excel(x)

Comment: And do you have any alternative solution for that?

Comment: yes df is correct, you could use `swifter` or `dask` to do the operation on the df itself